# Why can't CodeIgniter autoload my Exceptions file in application/core?

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception, include, classnotfound

I have an exception in application/core named prefix_Exceptions.php with the same class name. I try to throw this exception from a controller and I get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'prefix_Exceptions' not found in user_controller.php
```

In `application/core/prefix_Exceptions.php`:

```
<?php
class prefix_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function test() {
        echo "This is a test.";
    }
}
```

And in `application/controllers/user_controller.php`:

```
<?php
class User_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function view($id = '0') {
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $u = $this->user_model->getUser($id);

        if (!isset($u)) {
            $this->exceptions->test(); // ???
        }
        echo "Test: $u";
    }
}
```

Oh, and my prefix is set to `prefix_`:

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'prefix_';
```

I've read about a dozen threads on this issue and none of them fix my exception so that it can be thrown by the controller.

Comment: I guess you're prefixing `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'prefix_';` in `application/config/config.php`, right?

Comment: Yes. How do I access a method in my Exceptions class now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main reason your code is not working, is (as the error message suggests): your `prefix_invalid_user.php` is never loaded. CI does not know to load this file, as you are not following the required file naming scheme.

If you want to extend a built-in class, you have to use the same class name, except you change the prefix from `CI_` to `MY_` (or whatever prefix you set in your config).

To extend the class `CI_Exceptions` you would have to name it `MY_Exceptions` and save that php file in `/application/core/MY_Exceptions.php`. Then, and only then, will CI auto-load it for you.

However you should also know that CI's exceptions class isn't actually for throwing exceptions (the name is misleading, but `CI_Exceptions` handles error reporting). As you can see in the `/system/core/Exceptions.php` file, the `CI_Exceptions` class does not extend PHP's native `Exceptions` class, which is necessary to create custom, throwable exceptions.

If you want custom, throwable exceptions you have to create your own wrapper for them, and load/autoload it as a library.

**Edit:**

As per the OP's request, I'm adding the other half of the solution, which was to simply fetch the class object from CI's innards. For this, we can use the `load_class` function, which will return our class object if it has been instantiated, and if not, it will instantiate and return it.

```
$foo = load_class('Exceptions', 'core', $this->config->item('subclass_prefix'))
```

Then we can access the methods of our custom Exceptions class as so:

```
$foo->someMethodName();
```

Comment: Also, based on the second part of your question, I won't try to throw it anymore, but I would still like to have it loading.

Comment: You named your file `prefix_Exceptions.php` and named your class `prefix_Exceptions`?

Comment: It is now. How do I access a method in prefix_Exceptions.php?

Comment: First you fetch the `prefix_Exceptions` class object, by doing: `$foo = load_class('Exceptions', 'core', $this->config->item('subclass_prefix'));`. Then you can call `$foo->someMethod()`.

Comment: It worked! You should put that load_class bit in your answer, because that's partially what I was missing and it's nowhere in the CodeIgniter documentation. Thank you.

Comment: It's not in the documentation because it's a core function, I found it when digging through the CI source code

Comment: If they're going to tell you [how to extend core system classes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html), they should tell you how to load them.